# How would I create this "X" delete button in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes

I'm trying to create this little "X" in Photoshop but I can't figure out how to exactly recreate this.

I tried creating 2 rectangles and rotating them +45 degrees and -45 degrees, but then the intersection is not a closed path.

How would I do this in Photoshop (or Illustrator)?

[image: delete]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Type a +
- Find an appropriate font
- Rotate 45°

[image: fonts]

You could further edit by highlighting the type layer for the X and then choose Type > Convert to Shape from the menu to have a shape layer. Save the shape layer as a Custom Shape (Edit menu) and you'd then simply need to use the Shape tools if you ever needed it again.

Comment: omg... haha I never thought of typing in a "+"... I always typed in a "x". thanks! I feel so stupid :D

Comment: Sometimes the simplest solutions are the most elusive :) Glad to help.

Comment: totally agree. thanks for the "aha" moment :)

Comment: Yep. I call that "When in doubt, cheat."

Comment: haha! plus! brilliant!

Answer (score 11):

If you want this as a vector shape in Photoshop:

- Select the Rectangle Tool (U)
- Turn on Grid View (View -> Show -> Grid) and Snap to Grid (View -> Snap To -> Grid)
- Draw the first part, and then draw the cross part using the Shift key to add it to the same Shape Layer. (You need only hold Shift while you're clicking, let go of it once you begin to draw the shape.)

[image: Step 1]

- Press Cmd (Ctrl) + T and rotate it 45 deg (while holding *Shift* to snap).

[image: Step 2]

Comment: how do I combine the 2 rectangles then so that I can do like inner glows and strokes?

Comment: If you do it as I described (holding Shift when you draw the second part) then it should be a single vector shape. If you don't want to see the lines you can combine the paths: http://i.imgur.com/EXyZw.png

Comment: holding Shift makes it the second rectangle a square

Comment: Ah, sorry, I wasn't clear there. You should hold Shift at first, so you see the little '+' and *then* let go of Shift — So... Shift, Click, Let go of Shift, Drag ;)

Comment: This is definitely the better way to go, in my opinion. Gives more control and accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

How about finding an X in Zapf Dingbats or Wingdings? That particular X is a 6 in Zapf Dingbats.